# does not display Items in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, itemscontrol

I try to view items in ScrollViewer but it display nothing

There is Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Ok. I make some changes in c# cod but it still does not work:

```
public class MyItem
{
    string text;
    public string Text
        {
            set { text = value;  }
            get { return text; }
        }
}
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> myList { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        myList = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        myList.Add(new MyItem() { Text = "Abkhazia" });
        myList.Add(new MyItem() { Text = "Afghanistan" });
        myList.Add(new MyItem() { Text = "Albania" }); 

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few reasons:

1. Your observablecollection needs to be public.
2. Your observablecollection should be a property.

   public class MyClass
   {

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<MyItem> myList {get; set;}


   public MyClass()
   {

       DataContext=this;
       myList = new ObservableCollection();

       myList.Add(new MyItem() { Text = "Abkhazia" });
       myList.Add(new MyItem() { Text = "Afghanistan" });
       myList.Add(new MyItem() { Text = "Albania" });
   }
   ```

   }

Also keep in mind if your modifying "MyItem" it needs to support INotifyPropertyChanged or your display will NOT update.

Comment: it still does not view items.

Comment: Your missing a line. Add this to your constructor: DataContext = this;

Comment: Where it needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

You should define `ItemTemplate` properly:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Then show how `myList` is exposed in your view model class. According to this XAML, `ItemsControl` should have `DataContext` property set to view model, which has public `myList` property.